# How to send data json via AJAX to my controller in symfony?

Tags: ajax, symfony, controller

I'm having a bad time trying to send data via ajax to my symfony conbtroller, but it seems that I don't get it on my controller, I can't even test it if it arrieve correctly.

I'm working on symfony 3.3, I've try the documentation and other answers here on stackoverflow, but I can't work it around, so could someone please let me know what I'm doing it wrong?

my JS script on my twig view:

```
        $.blockUI({ message: '<h4><img src="{{ asset('assets/global/plugins/cubeportfolio/cubeportfolio/img/cbp-loading.gif') }}" /> Guardando datos, por favor espere...</h4>' });
        var form = document.getElementById("idUsuario").value;

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ path('followingAction') }}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {form: form},
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (returndata) {
                Notificacion("success", "Survey Project", "Empezaste a seguir a este usuario");
                $.unblockUI();
                $('#sample_2').load(window.location + ' #sample_2 >  *');

            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                Notificacion("error", "Survey Project", "Ha existido un problema y no se ha podido seguir a este usuario.");
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });
```

and here is the code in my controller, I can't do var_dump or see any error or anything:

```
     * @Route("/following/", name="followingAction")
     * Method({"GET", "POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function followingAction(Request $request)
    {



        $request->isXmlHttpRequest();

        $id = $request->query->get('form');

        var_dump("doesn't work");die;



        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


        $user = $em->getRepository('ModelBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id ));
        $seguidor = $em->getRepository('ModelBundle:Followers')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id ));
        $seguido = $em->getRepository('ModelBundle:Followers')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id ));

        $follower = new Followers();
        //$follower->setUsername($seguidor->getUsername());
        $follower->setUserId($seguidor->getId());
        $follower->setSeguidoId($user->getId());
        $em->persist($follower);
        $em->flush();
        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true);
        $response = new Response(json_encode($response));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
```

and here is my imports in the controller:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use ModelBundle\Entity\User;
use ModelBundle\Entity\Categoria;
use ModelBundle\Entity\Followers;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
```

Comment: check your browser console.

Comment: as habibun says, check your browser console, especially the network tab. make sure, that the request you send actually contains data. afterwards, check the docs on the `Request`, because `$request->query` usually only contains GET stuff, and your request appears to be POST. so ... `$request->request`, possibly. you should check the browser console because the format in which data is sent may not be, what you'd expect. if it's sent as form encoded ... may very well work, if it's just json in the body, it may very well not.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jakumi for your answer, your answer was concrete and well explained, I didn't know that I need to check the network tab for ajax requests, so was there where I could find the problem and then I tried other things 'till I found the solution.